# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications error while establishing connection

Tags: windows, jdbc, ingres

I am trying to connect  my Ingrees Database Workbranch to Ingres DB  and resiving this error

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications error while establishing connection.
at com.ingres.gcf.util.SqlExType.getSqlEx(SqlExType.java:97)
at com.ingres.gcf.util.SqlExFactory.get(SqlExFactory.java:68)
at com.ingres.gcf.util.SqlExFactory.get(SqlExFactory.java:158)
at com.ingres.gcf.util.SqlExFactory.get(SqlExFactory.java:197)
at com.ingres.gcf.dam.MsgIo.connect(MsgIo.java:357)
at com.ingres.gcf.dam.MsgOut.connect(MsgOut.java:325)
at com.ingres.gcf.dam.MsgIn.connect(MsgIn.java:343)
at com.ingres.gcf.dam.MsgConn.<init>(MsgConn.java:274)
at com.ingres.gcf.jdbc.DrvConn.connect(DrvConn.java:716)
at com.ingres.gcf.jdbc.DrvConn.<init>(DrvConn.java:462)
at com.ingres.gcf.jdbc.JdbcDrv.connect(JdbcDrv.java:590)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:206)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:104)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:53)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ingres.internal.connectivity.IngresConnectionFactory.createConnection(IngresConnectionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:355)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I am using Ingres JDBC Driver URL looks like `jdbc:ingres://internal_IP:ii7/DBName`

Did I miss something? Internet didn't give any solution. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? It looks like you are missing the exception cause.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes it is. full error